# Does Collections.unmodifiableMap (and others) violate SOLID principles?

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles

I was recently reading `Java Concurrency in Practice` and was exposed to the `Collections.unmodifiableMap(...)` method for the first time. The method creates a read-only wrapper around an existing `Map` and any attempts to modify the returned `Map` will (according to the `Javadocs`) result in an `UnsupportedOperationException` being thrown. Similar methods exist for other collection classes.

This made me quite concerned since an `unmodifiableMap()` still returns a `Map`, but does not support all relevant methods. The fact that it also throws exceptions on write operations means it cannot substitute a "proper" `Map` in most applications.

I am a student and am not yet confident in my ability to recognize design flaws, but aren't these violations of the `Interface segregation` and `Liskov substitution` principles, respectively?

Comment: It strikes me that it might not violate the I-principle, as that pertains to the creator of the interfaces, not the clients.

Comment: The `Map` interface documents that implementations may choose not to support all of its methods.  Honestly, it's a design compromise that works just fine in practice.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks, I had missed that. If you make it an answer I'll close the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Map interface documents that implementations may choose not to support all of its methods, which makes `Collections.unmodifiableMap` return an implementation that satisfies the interface contract.

While it's unusual for an interface to make implementing its methods "optional" in this way, it's a design compromise that works just fine in practice.  Most collections *should* be written only once and then read from again and again, so code that modifies a map is usually the code that created it and knows that it is mutable.

Comment: I would have preferred a separation of `Map` and `MutableMap` where the latter extends the former (same with the other collections). The mutable versions should also have a method which returns a read-only view (e.g. `Map<K,V> asReadOnlyMap()`), possibly returning a cached instance (up to the implementation), to prevent any downcasting when exposing said collection.

Comment: @Slaw, you may be interested in http://blog.codefx.org/java/immutable-collections-in-java/.

Comment: @jaco0646 Interesting blog :) It basically ends up at the same solution I would have preferred, just with an extra _immutable_ version of the interface as well (I was only going with read-only/read-write in the same vein as unmmodifiable collections now, just without the confusion of mutator methods being present in read-only _references_). Though I agree, unfortunately, with the poster that this will never be implemented in Java due to it breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: The first practical problem that comes up with that is the type of `MutableMap.keySet`, which can support removals but not addition, or `Arrays.asList`, which supports `set` but not `add` or `remove`.  Capturing that level of detail in explicit interfaces becomes impractical fast.

Comment: @Louis Yes, there are still some issues and some methods will still have to be documented to throw `UnsupportedOperationException`, but I would have preferred such "half measures" instead of the complete lack of read-only/immutable collection types.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the ISP, Bob Martin would likely consider `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` to produce a violation in the same vein as his [stack class example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55073007/1371329). It exposes clients to an interface they do not need, and in fact cannot use.

As previously mentioned, the LSP is satisfied by the interface documentation.